# Linq where with nested .Any() in string variable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate

These are my entities:

```
public class Subscription : BaseItem
    {
        public virtual DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }
        public virtual int Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Theater Theater { get; set; }
        public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
    }

public class Account : BaseItem
    {
        public virtual string LegalName { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string UrlName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
        public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public virtual string Country { get; set; }
        public virtual string Tel { get; set; }
        public virtual string Tel2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
        public virtual string Mobile { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Website { get; set; }
        public virtual int DefaultVatRate { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Bankrupt { get; set; }
        public virtual string ExternalId { get; set; }
        public virtual bool DoNotContact { get; set; }     
        public virtual bool NotInterested { get; set; }    
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Header> Headers { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    }

public class Order : BaseItem
    {
        public virtual int Number { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual double Amount { get; set; }
        public virtual string Attachment { get; set; }
        public virtual string AttachmentFilename { get; set; }
        public virtual string AttachmentMimetype { get; set; }
        public virtual bool? PaidToTheater { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? DatePaidToTheater { get; set; }
        public virtual bool? CashinByTheater { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Theater Theater { get; set; }
        public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<OrdersAttachment> OrdersAttachments { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<OrdersDueDate> OrdersDueDates { get; set; }
        public virtual Header Header { get; set; }
    }

public class Invoice : BaseItem
    {
        public virtual int Number { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual double Amount { get; set; }
        public virtual double VatRate { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsSendMail { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<InvoicesDueDate> InvoicesDueDates { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<InvoicesPayment> InvoicesPayments { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a method in my program that build a "query" in a string variable.

```
private string GenerateQuery(FilterSubscription filterSubscription)
{
    if (filterSubscription.FilterByOrder)
       return "Account.Orders.Any()";
    if (filterSubscription.FilterByInvoice)
       return "Account.Orders.Any(Invoices.Any())";  //here is my problem
}
```

This is the call to the method

```
string query = GenerateQuery(filterSubscription)
var count = Session.Linq<Subscription>().Where(query).Count();
```

If I need to extract all accounts that have at least one Order is all OK.
But if I need to extract all accounts that have at least one Invoice I don't know how.
If I wrote

```
var count = Session.Linq<Subscription>().Where(s=>s.Account.Orders.Any(o=>o.Invoices.Any())).Count();
```

it works but if I use the string variable it doesn't.

Comment: What happens exactly? do you get an error?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque when calling the .Count() method with the string "Account.Orders.Any(Invoices.Any())" I get an **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**. Instead with the string "Account.Orders.Any(o => o.Invoices.Any())", I get a **ParseException** with message "No property or field 'o' exists in type 'Order'"

Comment: BTW, you tagged your question "entity framework", but `Session.Linq` is something from NHibernate... I tried your code with in-memory data and it works fine, so it might be something wrong with NHibernate

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should return a delegate from GenerateQuery instead - something like:

```
private Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> GenerateQuery(FilterSubscription filterSubscription)
{
  if (filterSubscription.FilterByOrder)
    return s => s.Account.Orders.Any();
  if (filterSubscription.FilterByInvoice)
    return s => s.Account.Orders.Any(o => o.Invoices.Any());
}
```

Then just update the query variable to be implicitly typed:

```
var query = GenerateQuery(filterSubscription);
```

Comment: I suspect he's using Dynamic Linq, which allows to use a string predicate

Comment: Anyway, the method should return an `Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>>`, not a `Func<Subscription, bool>`

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLevesque - edited to return an expression instead. I'd prefer to use expressions over dynamic Linq for predefined queries to pick up errors at compile time, there may be other reasons why that isn't possible in this case.